# WARNING:root:failed to insert values - insert not always successful to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database

My script usually inserts the data to MySQL database correctly, however, when I schedule it to run every 10 seconds (this scheduling calls this script every 10s) it crashes about 50% of the time.

Any suggestions?

```
some unimportant code here

# Calculate pulse length
elapsed = stop-start

# Distance pulse travelled in that time is time
# multiplied by the speed of sound (cm/s)
distance = elapsed * speedSound

# That was the distance there and back so halve the value
distance = distance / 2
distance = '{:f}'.format(distance)

    print(distance)

time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(time)
# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.2.3","sonic","123456","Pi" )


cursor = db.cursor()


sql = "INSERT INTO UltraSonic (distance, time) VALUES (%s, %s)"

try:

    cursor.execute(sql, (distance, time))

    db.commit()

# Rollback in case there is any error
#   db.rollback()
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    logging.warn("failed to insert values %s, %s", distance, time)
# disconnect from server
finally:
    db.close()
print ("Ok")
```

Comment: Please include any errors you're encountering. You may want to remove your "except MySQLdb.IntegrityError" so you can get at the real exception being thrown as opposed to just logging a warning.

Comment: not usre if this is correct output, I just removed the exception from the code:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sonic.py", line 80, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, (distance, time))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '17.384983' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Comment: You're attempting to insert a row that would violate the table's rules. You'll have to adjust your table or your code to ensure that doesn't happen.

Comment: well, thats interesting, as sometimes it does write the values... I try to check the table..

Comment: Well it *will* write the values that don't violate the table's rules, it's only when you attempt to insert something that would fail do you get an exception.

Comment: it is always the number and the date, number should be formated to have always the same length

Comment: looks like a problem with duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in DB table, Key was set to PRI, what did not allow duplicate entries, which I need.

removing PRI solved the issue. thanks joeb!!